# Groups having no maximal cyclic subgroups of prime order

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, maximal-subgroup

Is there any classification of groups which do not contain maximal cyclic subgroups of prime order p, for any prime p ?

Your suggestions will be highly useful.

Comment: what do you meal by maximal cyclic subgroups of prime order $p$?

Comment: By a maximal cyclic subgroup of prime order p, I mean a cyclic subgroup of prime order p that is not contained in any other cyclic subgroup.

Comment: In my opinion the classification could be difficult, only some broad classification can be *expected* but I dont know. In particular, consider finite $p$-groups of nilpotency class $2$ such that $x^p=1$ for all $x$; the classification of this small family is even much difficult.